# Swift - Adding UITableView protocols

Tags: swift, ios8

I am following Apple documentation ([page link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html)) to add a tableview in empty ViewController.swift file. While adding protocols as shown below:

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
// define the class
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:    Int) -> Int {
return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->        UITableViewCell! {
let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")

cell.text = "Row #\(indexPath.row)"
cell.detailTextLabel.text = "Subtitle #\(indexPath.row)"

return cell
}
```

I am getting error: “Type ViewController Does not confirm to protocol UITableViewDataSource. There's nothing much to do here. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 required functions are not within the class definition. Just move the closing bracket of the class to the end of the file.